# Why does this doubly-linked-list program give me a null-pointer exception?

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Basically, the problem is:

- Given a list of chars, do the following until it has only 1 element:

  1. Starting from the beginning, remove each second node of the list, for example  doing this to "abcdefghij" should return "acegi"
  2. Starting from the end of the list produced by step 1, remove each second node, so doing this to "acegi" should return "aei"
  3. Do these steps until the list has only 1 element

The final solution to this particular list should be "i".

My solution to this is :

```
public class listexercise {

    public static DLL<Character> removeFront(DLL<Character> list){

        DLLNode<Character> tmp = list.getFirst().succ;

        while(tmp != null){
            list.delete(tmp);
                if(tmp.succ == null) {
                    tmp.pred.succ = null;
                    break;
                }
            tmp = tmp.succ.succ;
        }

        return list;

    }
    public static DLL<Character> removeEnd(DLL<Character> list){

        DLLNode<Character> tmp = list.getLast().pred;

        while(tmp != null){
            list.delete(tmp);
            if(tmp.pred == null) {
                tmp.succ.pred = null;
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.pred.pred;
        }

        return list;        
    }
    public static DLL<Character> rec(DLL<Character> list, int n){
        if(list.length() == 1)
            return list;
        else if(n%2 == 1)
            return rec(removeFront(list), n++);
        else if(n%2 == 0)
            return rec(removeEnd(list), n++);

            return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        DLL<Character> list = new DLL<Character>();
        String input = s.nextLine();
        char[] parts = input.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
            list.insertLast(parts[i]);

        System.out.println(rec(list,1).toString());
    }
}
```

This gives me NPE on the removeFront or removeEnd. However if I use specifically only one of them at a time, they work perfectly, but when I put them in a recursion, there's a problem.

Any ideas how to fix this??

Comment: What would `getFirst()` return if the list is empty?

Comment: `null`, but the list never gets empty

Comment: So I guess it's a doubly-linked, circular list.

Comment: Yes. This is the implementation https://pastebin.com/E41EBgbX

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera David, I'm not asking what a NullPointerException is, I ask what can be causing it in this particular program.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other issues, but `rec(removeFront(list), n++)` is very apparent one here. This statement will do the method call, then increment the value of `n` which will never be used.

Change this to `rec(removeFront(list), n+1)`